# Is it appropriate to use Factory/delegate pattern to handle exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns

I am working on a library that handles connection with various imap servers (mail provider) like (Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo, Orange ...).

Into the subject, One method request the access token using a refresh token (OAuth2), this method may throw an exception for many reasons, (access revoked, invalidParameter, badRequest, invalidCredentials, dailyLimitExceeded, or no connection... [Google Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors)).

So for example, if I got a revoked access exception, I should handle it, so the next time, the user connect, we ask for his consent.
If I got a too many request exception, then I handle it by backing off...

**The question: Is it appropriate to use Factory/delegate (C#) pattern to handle the different type of exceptions? Or should I handle it differently?**

Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Comment: so you are asking for our opinions on code we do not see? uhmm...

Comment: IMHO a delegate in this case sounds reasonable, I'd attempt to keep the code simple and readable. Having lots of lines in the `catch` will probably degrade readability so I don't see why not. Not sure, however, about the factory pattern here, do you really want to create objects in the `catch`?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I'm just asking if it is appropriate to use a delegate to handle different exceptions, i don't see in what code will be helpful. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you @oleksii for your response, It is just that i have a lot of different error response messages for each one of the 5 imap servers, in time, we may add 10 to 15 more. And yes i'm rather for a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

First to obey the open/closed principle you should write a base class or interface with a "void HandleError(Exception exception)" method or similiar. Then you derive a class for every error you like to handle. If you use any IoC/DI Container, it could create all possible handlers for you. Otherwise, your initialization has to create all instances.

If you look for patterns, I could imagine that Visitor or Chain Of Responsibility could be candidates, depending on the details you didn't give us.